# On the addition of HCl to a conjugated diene

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, c-c-addition

[image]

Is this allylic chloride formed by an ionic or radical mechanism? Is it the more stable isomer?

Comment: Don't base product distributions on thermodynamics unless there is an equilibrium that can be established. You should be looking at kinetic considerations instead.

Comment: I wonder if this actually _is_ a free radical reaction. Afaik, the peroxide effect operates only in the case of HBr...

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: But the question still remains unsolved.

Comment: Which is the best site for the carbocation?

Comment: Peroxides affect the regioselectivity with HBr. It will certainly help promote the radical pathway here.

Comment: Hmm, well, maybe not: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01650a041?journalCode=jacsat

Answer (score 0):

Benzylic carbocation is formed as it is stable due to resonance.
So Cl attaches to benzylic position.
More substituted alkenes are more stable so the terminal double bond changes its position.
(Also this isn’t free radical reaction)